# Why the function has to be a periodic function, if we want to find its Fourier series?

Tags: fourier-transform, mathematics

1. Why the function has to be a periodic function, if we want to find its [Fourier series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series)?
2. What happens if the function has non-zero values over a finite range only?

   e.g.

   $ f(x) = e^{-x}; 0 \le x \le 5 $

   $ f(x) = 0 ; otherwise$

Comment: There's a key difference between Fourier series and the Fourier transform. The latter deals with functions, and those functions don't have to be periodic.

Comment: And you can always say that your function has the period equal to infinity. Of course the resulting series will be infinite then.

Comment: The Fourier transform is the decomposition into eigenfunctions of the Laplace operator. On a compact space such as a torus, the spectrum of the Laplace operator is discrete. Thus the Fourier transform on a torus is a series. Working with periodic functions is the same as working on a torus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The Fourier series has terms like $\sin \left(\frac {2\pi n t}P \right)$ After time $P$ all the terms will repeat, so the Fourier series can only represent functions that have period $P$.  Many functions in nature are periodic, so these series can represent a lot of things we are interested in.  The fixed period makes the various terms orthogonal, so evaluating the coefficients is easy.
2. The Fourier transform, with a continuous range of frequencies, can handle nonperiodic functions.  For your given function, you can compute the Fourier transform, getting a function of a continuous range of frequencies.  Sometimes it is useful to change your function into a periodic one, pretending it repeats with period $5$.  This will give you a discrete spectrum, where all the frequencies are multiples of $\frac 15$

Comment: Can I build above mentioned exponential function using series of these two functions (with coefficients multiplications ): $f_1(x) = sin(x) ; 0\le x \le 5; $ and $ f_1(x) = 0 ; otherwise $ and second function as $f_2(x) = cos(x);  0\le x \le 5;$ and $f_2(x) = 0 ; otherwise$ ?

Comment: No, you need an infinite number of them.  You can use $\sin \frac {2 \pi n t}5$ and the similar cosine to cover the range $0 \le  t \le 5$  The resulting series will be periodic with period $5$, so if you sum the series for $t=6$ the value at $6$ will be $e^{-1}$, not $e^{-6}$

Comment: So you mean we can not use "truncated" sine and cosine terms to "build" any non-periodic function, even though these truncated terms are infinite in numbers ? By "truncated" I mean not taking one complete cycle of sine and cosine functions; as if someone has chopped off some part of sine/cosine curves. Functions $f1$ and $f2$ mentioned above are "truncated" sine/cosine functions. Am I correct ?

Comment: Yes, you can do that.  The truncated functions can model anything that is continuous enough.  It is no different than extending your function by periodicity and using the standard Fourier series except by your definition the function is zero outside the interval.

Comment: Sorry. I did not get you, since my statement in previous comment was "So you mean we can NOT use......infinite in numbers? ". Which one is correct : "I can build non-periodic function" OR "I can NOT build non-periodic function"  using truncated sines/cosines? Sorry again, but I am slow learner!